# Read element within elements using XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, xmltextreader

I am reading `XML data` and retrieving the values based on the `element`. There is one element named `<UniqueColumns>` which can have child element called `<string>`. I want to read those values and add it to the `ObservableCollection<String>`. If there are no values then don't anything. There are three scenarios as following:

Scenario - 1: More than 1 child elements.

```
<IndexId>4</IndexId>
<UniqueColumns>
  <string>Dir_nbr</string>
  <string>Dir_name</string>
</UniqueColumns>
<SelectedTableForUniqColumn>TBDirectory</SelectedTableForUniqColumn>
```

Scenario - 2: Only one child element.

```
<IndexId>4</IndexId>
<UniqueColumns>
  <string>Dir_nbr</string>
</UniqueColumns>
<SelectedTableForUniqColumn>TBDirectory</SelectedTableForUniqColumn>
```

Scenario - 3: No child element.

```
<IndexId>4</IndexId>
<UniqueColumns/>
<SelectedTableForUniqColumn>TBDirectory</SelectedTableForUniqColumn>
```

Code:

```
//This is a user defined data object and it has parameter which is type of `ObservableCollection<String>`. 
ExternalDatabaseTableRequestDO req = new ExternalDatabaseTableRequestDO();

using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlData)))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int result;
        long res;
        string parameterValue;
        ObservableCollection<String> parameterValueList = new ObservableCollection<String>();

        switch (reader.Name.ToLower())
        {
            case "indexid":
                parameterValue = reader.ReadString();
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameterValue) && Int32.TryParse(parameterValue, out result))
                   req.IndexId = result;
                break;

            case "uniquecolumns":
                //need loop logic here but not sure how to do that.
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) // This will give me parent element which is <UniqueColumns>
                {
                    //Stuck here. How to read child elements if exists.
                }
                break;

            case "selectedtableforuniqcolumn":
                parameterValue = reader.ReadString();
                req.SelectedTableForUniqColumn = parameterValue;
                break;
        }
    }
}
return req;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Linq2Xml?

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
//var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var strings = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//UniqueColumns/string")
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: for some reason I'm getting error `'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'XPathSelectElements'`.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it but getting another error `Illegal characters in path.`

Comment: @Robinhood If you give an *xml string* to XDocument use `XDocument.Parse` method. `XDocument.Load` loads the xml from a file. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I've posted my approach below.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This will give me all child element values if they exists   
 var columnList = XElement.Parse(xmlData).Descendants("string").ToList();

        if (columnList != null)
        {
            foreach (var column in columnList)
                parameterValueList.Add(column.Value);
        }
```